# I need help regarding sentence diagramming

Tags: sentence, diagramming

How would you diagram a sentence in which two independent clauses are connected by a semicolon? Do you draw them the same as conjunctions, or is it something else?

I looked around the internet and got nil answers. Please show me the way to tackling this problem, and thank you in advance.

Comment: Just draw the tree as the sentence is written, i.e. with a semicolon.